# Filtering by title inside the category(many-to-many)

Tags: python, django

I have a page where I can choose the category of my item, then it takes me to a different template and display all the items with that category. What needs to be made, so I can filter these results further, by lets say a title?

views.py thats the function that filters my items by category and takes my to search.html template

```
def category_view(request, category_id):
  item_list = Item.objects.filter(category__pk=category_id)

  return render(request, "search.html", {'item_list': item_list})
```

search.html

```
    <div class="offset-md-1 col-md-2">
    <h2>Content Filter</h2> <br>
    <form method="GET" action=".">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-12">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" type="search" name="q"
                        placeholder="Brand..">
                    <span class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Below that there's just a list that displays the results

views.py I tried doing it this way, but I get an error "Page not found (404)" "The current path, bike-category/, didn't match any of these. "

```
def SearchView(request):
  item_list = Item.objects.all()
  query = request.GET.get('q')
  if query:
      item_list = Item.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)

  context = {
      'item_list': item_list
  }
  return render(request, "search.html", context)
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('bikes/', BikeView, name='bikes'),
   path('', HomeView, name='home'),
   path('search/', SearchView, name='search'),
   path('bike-category/<category_id>', category_view, name='category')
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form action is taking you back to the same page, but with no `category_id`. That gives you a 404, because you don't have a url path defined for `'bike-category/'`. You need to set your action to `'search/'`, or better yet use the `url` template tag with the name of your path like so:

```html
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}">
```

That should take care of the 404 error, because the form should submit to `'search/'`, and Django will pass the request to your `SearchView` class.

If you want to search only within a category, you'll need to tell the `SearchView` which category. You can do this a few ways, but since you're already running this search from a category view, the simplest way might be to create a new url to search within a category, but using the same view:

```py
urlpatterns = [
   path('bikes/', BikeView, name='bikes'),
   path('', HomeView, name='home'),
   path('search/', SearchView, name='search'),
   path('search/<category_id>', SearchView, name='category_search'),
   path('bike-category/<category_id>', category_view, name='category')
]
```

Then you can modify your view to accept this:

```py
def SearchView(request, category_id=None):
    if category_id:
        category = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)
        item_list = Item.objects.filter(category__id=category_id)
    else:
        category = None
        item_list = Item.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        item_list = item_list.filter(title__icontains=query)

    context = {
        'item_list': item_list,
        'category': category
    }
  return render(request, "search.html", context)
```

Note, we take `category_id` as a parameter, but give it a default value of `None` so non-category searching still works. We then filter to that category first if it is passed in. Finally, we add the query to our category filter by filtering on `item_list` rather than `Item.objects`.

We'll also need to update our form action to use this new path:

```html
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'category_search' category.id %}">
```

And finally we need to pass the category to the `search.html` template in the context data:

```py
def category_view(request, category_id):
    category = Category.objects.get(pk=category_id)
    item_list = Item.objects.filter(category__pk=category_id)

    return render(request, "search.html", {'item_list': item_list, 'category': category})
```

Comment: Yeah no error this time, but when I search for title it filters through all the results, not only within that category

Comment: I updated my answer. By the way, you shouldn't use `UpperCase` names for functions in python. Those should be reserved for classes. This view should be called `search_view`.

Comment: I have updated the code, but still the same thing is happening. When i search it takes me to `http://localhost:8000/search/?q=rondo` instead of `localhost:8000/bike-category/1/?q=rondo`. I think that i need to change the action in my html to category_search, but when I do it I get `Reverse for 'category_search' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['search/(?P<category_id>[^/]+)$']`

Comment: Ah yes, you do need to update your action, but it needs to include the argument. See my last update.

Comment: still the same error `Reverse for 'category_search' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['search/(?P<category_id>[^/]+)$']`  it points to this line `return render(request, "search.html", {'item_list': item_list})` in my category_view

Comment: Sorry - I see now you haven't passed the category to that template, so it's passing a blank string to the view. Try editing `category_view` as I outlined.

Comment: Ok, so after adding that stuff to the category_view I could open the page with all results for category filter and I was getting the same error when i was trying to search for title. I added the same thing to the SearchView and now everything works. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207687/discussion-between-greg-kaleka-and-menor).